# What will if i pass in a null as 2 parameter and true as 3 parameter in inflate method in Android

Tags: android, view, layout-inflater, android-inflate

What will if i pass in a null as 2 parameter and true as 3 parameter in inflate method in Android?
I know that if i do something like this:

```
LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.children, parent)
```

R.layout.children will appear as a children of parent. Did i got it right?
But if i pass like this

```
LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.children, null, false)
```

It will return me a R.layout.children, without parent, because parent passed as null.
But what will if i pass like this?

```
LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.children, null)
```

What should R.layout.children as children join? The parents are null, and the third parameter is true by default. That is, there will be an addView implicitly. But to what?

Comment: Documentation exists: :)https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)

Comment: @crazo7924 a little bit confused)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the source code for `inflate`:

```
    public View inflate(@LayoutRes int resource, @Nullable ViewGroup root) {
        return inflate(resource, root, root != null);
    }
```

you can see that `root` is optional and if `null` the third parameter is `false` and then no View attached to the parent ViewGroup.

Comment: @user425799 No need to thank me